# How do I solve typescript/react error TS7053?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got an error :
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ name: string; isLandlocked: boolean; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ name: string; isLandlocked: boolean; }'.

My code looks like:

```
//some array

const questions: {name: string, quest: string}[] = [
    {name: "Is the square blue?",
      quest: "isBlue"}
  ]; //there's gonna be more elements in this array eventually

(...)
//my state
this.state = {
      colorsList: colors.map(value => (value.name)),
      questionIndex: Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length),
    };
(...)
//handle click on answer button (let's say we always use "no")
handleAnswer() {

let questionValue: string = questions[this.state.questionIndex].quest;

this.setState(color=> ({colorsList: state.colorsList.filter((value) =>
   !states[states.findIndex(element => element.name === value)][questionValue])}))
  }
(...)
//the button
<button id="no" onClick={this.handleAnswer}>NO</button>
```

Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435042/how-can-i-define-an-array-of-objects Create type or use indexes with quotation marks when assigning value.

Comment: What do you mean by "create type" ? I thought I created the type here ```const questions: {name: string, quest: string}[]``` and here ```let questionValue: string```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something weird in  your code.

`questionValue` is a string (e.g. `isBlue`) and `questions` is an array of `{name: string, quest: string}`. You are trying to access a position of  `questions` array using a string, while the only indexing you have so far is numbers. In other words, you are trying to access something like `questions['isBlue']`  rather than `questions[0]`.

If you want to create a string indexed, than you should create a type like the following:

```js
type QuestionType = {[key: string]: {name: string, quest: string}}
const questions:  QuestionType = {
  'blue': {name: 'test', quest: 'thisQuest'}
}
```

Comment: Well, it steel does not work. The thing is my code does work when I do: ```this.setState(color=> ({colorsList: state.colorsList.filter((value) =>
   !states[states.findIndex(element => element.name === value)]["isLandlocked"])}))
  }``` but the problem appears when I'm trying to use the variable ```questionValue``` (which is a string "isLandlocked") intesad of just  a string ```"isLandlocked"```. This is why it is so confusing for me. I believe there is something wrong because it is my first time using typescript instead of javascript.