# Declaring array of objects in TypeScript? (TS1109: Expression expected)

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

I am trying to create an array of objects for my project, but during the build, I face this issue:

> TS1110: Type expected 
> TS1109: Expression expected

[image: error screenshot]

My array looks like this:

```
export let COUNTRIES: Array<{ name: string, segments: number[] }> = Array({
   "name":"Afghanistan",
   "segments":[
      4687,
      4787,
      4790,
      4795,
      4880
   ]},{
   "name":"Albania",
   "segments":[
      4136,
      4248
   ]})
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435042/how-can-i-define-an-array-of-objects) from Stack Overflow but to no results.

---

Tried with an interface, having another issue:

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Which version of TypeScript are you using/compiling to?

Comment: I'm running typescript latest stable version, and the above code works

Comment: There is only 1 package which I use, it called `@graphprotocol/graph-ts": "0.19.0"`, not sure which version they use. Let me check

Comment: could try this and see if it works any better.
`let COUNTRIES: { name: string, segments: number[] }[] = whatever`

Comment: @Jacob the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone interested here is the final solution:

```
export class Country {
  name: string
  segments: number[]
}

export let COUNTRIES: Country[] = [
    {
    "name":"Afghanistan",
    "segments":[
       4687,
       4787,
       4790,
       4795,
       4880
    ]},{
    "name":"Albania",
    "segments":[
       4136,
       4248
    ]
}]
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the answer @Aadmaa provided considering that `class` works fundamentally similarly to `interfaces`

Comment: With interfaces it does not work for this enovirement.  Not sure whats the reason

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean this?

```
interface Country {
    name: string;
    segments: number[];
}

export let COUNTRIES: Country[] = [
    {
    "name":"Afghanistan",
    "segments":[
       4687,
       4787,
       4790,
       4795,
       4880
    ]},{
    "name":"Albania",
    "segments":[
       4136,
       4248
    ]
}]
```

Comment: Receiving this issue: `TS1003: Identifier expected. name: string,`

Comment: I guess there should be `;` instead of `,`

Comment: Having different issue with this option (check question updated description)