# Store a data table in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JS and want to store the table below in a variable.
I used dictionary like below. Maybe I'm wrong and it is not good.

```
<script>
    var dict = {}
    dict[0]['Name'] = "AD";
    dict[0]['Color'] = "Blue";
    dict[0]['Year'] = "2020";

    dict[1]['Name'] = "DC";
    dict[1]['Color'] = "Red";
    dict[1]['Year'] = "1809";

    dict[2]['Name'] = "FD";
    dict[2]['Color'] = "Green";
    dict[2]['Year'] = "2011";

    console.log(dict);
</script>
```

and all like that. But I only get the error output.

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'Name')

I need to feel data like this structure via Javascript. But I'm wrong. why? What is the problem?

See the picture I attached of the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09oj5.png)

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript - cannot set property of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479520/javascript-cannot-set-property-of-undefined)

Comment: It is complecated. I can't understand.

Comment: I think you are trying to make array of objects
[these answers could help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435042/how-can-i-define-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: @Pichai If fundamental JavaScript data structures are "*complicated* (sp.)", I would recommend re-visiting some more foundational-level introductory material to the language. Without this baseline knowledge, you'll find it a struggle to continue to build your skillset.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `dict` should be an array, rather than an object. Then, you should add the objects to the array. Example:

```js
let dict = [];
dict.push({'Name': 'AD', 'Color': 'Blue', 'Year': '2020'});
console.log(dict);
```

Comment: Is it a kind of json?

Comment: @Pichai JSON is a textual representation of Javascript data structures. If you aren't sure you understand the difference, i recommend finding some tutorials on Javascript types and datastructures. Make sure you understand the fundamentals.

Comment: @voiarn How add only one by one not all at one time?

Comment: @Pichai This way, you are adding each "row" of your table one by one to the `dict`. You are adding the entire row as an object at once. I don't see how it would help if you add Name, Color, Year one by one.

Comment: @voiam it is because I get the data from a json. Then I have to select only some vriables from all the json data. and then add some calculation and present the new data. This is why I have to select and store only some part of data.

Comment: @Pichai can you edit your question to show how you are actually intending to use this? It sounds like what you are trying to do is different from what you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the index you try to set as an object. However I would recommend using my example at index 3 instead. Alternatively you can an `array` instead of an `object`. I assume that you require key value pairs in this case.

```js
    var dict = {}
    dict[0] = {}
    dict[0]['Name'] = "AD";
    dict[0]['Color'] = "Blue";
    dict[0]['Year'] = "2020";

    dict[1] = {}
    dict[1]['Name'] = "DC";
    dict[1]['Color'] = "Red";
    dict[1]['Year'] = "1809";

    dict[2] = {}
    dict[2]['Name'] = "FD";
    dict[2]['Color'] = "Green";
    dict[2]['Year'] = "2011";

    // I would recommend doing it like this instead
    dict[3] = {Name: 'CD', Color: 'Red', Year: '2012'}

    console.log(dict);
```

Comment: I would edit your answer to use arrays as that makes the most sense.

Comment: I agree from what I can see an array would make the most sense, however the question refers to a dictionary and there already is a response that explains the array approach so I think changing my response wouldn't add any value to the question.

Comment: @VincentMenzel Your answer is good and close to what I want. the only problem is a new dictionary need to be defined each time.

Comment: @Pichai That's a not a problem, that's literally what is required to make it work.

Comment: The object has to be defined either way (when using an array or an dictionary)