# vue.js + typescript how to declare array of objects in data

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have this piece of code in  vue.js 3 + typescript, and I just want to declare an array of objects in my data, but several error pops up

```
<template>
  <ul >
    <li v-if="!items.length">...loading</li>
    <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <!--{{item}}-->
        <!--donde va {{item}} pongo un slot tag con un name y binding el item que voy a utilizar en el parent-->
        <slot name="item" v-bind="item"></slot>

    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'


export default defineComponent({
    name: 'child-slot-component',
    data() {
    return {
        items: []
    }
  },
    mounted() {
        setTimeout(() => {
      this.items = [
        { id: 1, body: 'Scoped Slots Guide', username: 'Evan You', likes: 20 },
        { id: 2, body: 'Vue Tutorial', username: 'Natalia Tepluhina', likes: 10 }
      ]
    }, 1000)
    },
})
</script>

<style  scoped>
    ul{
        list-style-type: none;
    }

</style>
```

id, body, username, and likes yell Type 'number' or 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
because in data when declaring items with empty array it says property:never and I wanted to declare something like this: {id:number, body:string,username:string, likes:number}[]

if is not correct what is the proper way to handle this declaration using typescript, or maybe I need to configure tsconfig.json or something

thanks in advance
Oh and the app works fine!!

this is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

this is my vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true
})
```

my babel config

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
  ]
}
```

my shims-vue.d.ts

```
/* eslint-disable */
declare module '*.vue' {
  import type { DefineComponent } from 'vue'
  const component: DefineComponent<{}, {}, any>
  export default component
}
```

and my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/vue3-essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off'
  }
}
```

is just the default configuration that brings vue create app-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining your items array with a type ahead of time should fix your TypeScript error. Something like this should work:

```
items: [] as { id: number, body: string, username: string, likes: number }[]
```

Comment: oh my , but how, where can I read more of this???

Comment: @MaykelContrerasCamacho This answer has some more detail:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35435042/how-can-i-define-an-array-of-objects

Comment: reading this post I was trying to do something like this let userTestStatus: { id: number, name: string }[] but it doesn t work without the '[ ] as' part

Comment: It might be because the data object is expecting data in a key value syntax using the `:` character, and you're defining your type with the same character. Try defining the type with `as` like I did